# Are regular expression a* and a.a* equal?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, kleene-star

a* = {λ, a, aa, aaa, aaaa.....}

a.a* = a.{λ, a, aa, aaa, aaaa.....} = {a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa....}

Then these two regular expressions above should not be equivalent. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: they are not equal

Comment: The second can be denoted $a^+$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is hardly anything significant that can be written as an answer.